# Python List Help

Tags: python, list

I have a list of lists that looks like:

```
floodfillque = [[1,1,e],[1,2,w], [1,3,e], [2,1,e], [2,2,e], [2,3,w]]

for each in floodfillque:
    if each[2] == 'w':
        floodfillque.remove(each)
    else:
        tempfloodfill.append(floodfillque[each[0+1][1]])
```

That is a simplified, but I think relevant part of the code.

Does the `floodfillque[each[0+1]]` part do what I think it is doing and taking the value at that location and adding one to it or no?  The reason why I ask is I get this error:

> TypeError: 'int' object is unsubscriptable

And I think I am misunderstanding what that code is actually doing or doing it wrong.

Comment: It is not safe to modify the sequence being iterated over in the loop: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to the bug in your code that other answers have already spotted, you have at least one more:

```
for each in floodfillque:
    if each[2] == 'w':
        floodfillque.remove(each)
```

**don't add or remove items from the very container you're looping on**.  While such a bug will usually be diagnosed only for certain types of containers (not including lists), it's just as terrible for lists -- it will end up altering your intended semantics by skipping some items or seeing some items twice.

If you can't substantially alter and enhance your logic (generally by building a new, separate container rather than mucking with the one you're looping on), the simplest workaround is usually to loop on a **copy** of the container you must alter:

```
for each in list(floodfillque):
```

Now, your additions and removals won't alter what you're actually looping on (because what you're looping on is a copy, a "snapshot", made once and for all at loop's start) so your semantics will work as intended.

Your specific approach to altering `floodfillque` also has a **performance** bug -- it behaves quadratically, while sound logic (building a new container rather than altering the original one) would behave linearly.  But, that bug is harder to fix without refactoring your code from the current not-so-nice logic to the new, well-founded one.

Answer (score 4):

Here's what's happening:

On the first iteration of the loop, `each` is `[1, 1, 'e']`. Since `each[2] != 'w'`, the `else` is executed.

In the `else`, you take `each[0+1][1]`, which is the same as `(each[0+1])[1]`. `each[0+1]` is `1`, and so you are doing `(1)[1]`. `int` objects can't be indexed, which is what's raising the error.

Comment: Okay, so then what is the solution?  if I want each[0] + 1 can I do that?

Comment: The solution to what? I'm just pointing out why the exception is raised. Your question is too unclear to give any other kind of answer.

Comment: How can I add 1 to the list index, basically.

Answer (score 3):

> Does the floodfillque[each[0+1] part
>   do what I think it is doing and taking
>   the value at that location and adding
>   one to it or no?

No, it sounds like you want `each[0] + 1`.

Either way, the error you're getting is because you're trying to take the second item of an integer... `each[0+1][1]` resolves to `each[1][1]` which might be something like `3[1]`, which doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I have a system in place to check to make sure that doesn't happen. But, maybe because I am modifying a list, that I am looping through that would cause this issue to occur?

Answer (score 3):

The other posters are correct. However, there is another bug in this code, which is that you are modifying `floodfillque` as you are iterating over it. This will cause problems, because Python internally maintains a counter to handle the loop, and deleting elements does not modify the counter.

The safe way to do this is to iterate of a copy of the loop:

```
for each in floodfillque[ : ]:
```

(`[ : ]` is Python's notation for a copy.)

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I understand NoahClark's intentions:

1. Remove those sublists whose third element is 'w'
2. For the remaining sublist, add 1 to the second item

If this is the case, the following will do:

```
# Here is the original list
floodfillque = [[1,1,'e'], [1,2,'w'], [1,3,'e'], [2,1,'e'], [2,2,'e'], [2,3,'w']]

# Remove those sublists which have 'w' as the third element
# For the rest, add one to the second element
floodfillque = [[a,b+1,c] for a,b,c in floodfillque if c != 'w']
```

This solution works fine, but it is not the most efficient: it creates a new list instead of patching up the original one.